# How to use TeXworks with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to use BibLaTeX with the Windy City style to produce Chicago author–date citations and a bibliography.

I have a TeX document:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[reflist=true,style=windycity]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Scenario}

Here is a claim I am citing \parencite{latexcompanion1993}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And I have the following file saved as `refs.bib` in the same directory:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion1993},
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

I open the TeX document in TeXworks, press compile with the default settings, and this is the output:

[image]

No bibliography is generated, and the citation just prints the identifier string instead of formatting it.

It seems the problem is that BibLaTeX cannot "find" `refs.bib`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it necessary to use Biber? What does Biber do that Biblatex doesn't do already?

Comment: Yes it is. `biber` does all the sorting  and processing of the `.bib` file, while `biblatex` formats everything. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693) for more details on the differences.

Comment: `biblatex` is just a LaTeX package that formats the bibliography data, the data itself still need to be read by Biber. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 which explains the whole process for LaTeX and BibTeX (but you can just read Biber instead of BibTeX and the bug picture will still be true).